# JPA without persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence.xml

I'm trying to get started with using Guice Persist and JPA, which recommends using configuration via persistence.xml.  Coming from a native Hibernate background where configuration was obtained programmatically, is there a simple way to configure a JpaPersistModule without a persistence.xml file, or will a rump persistence.xml always have to exist?

If no such option exists, it might be the case where I might have to play around with PersistenceProvider (assuming the "default" parses persistence.xml somehow).  Any tutorials on working with the JPA SPI?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for `persistence.xml` if you are using a Spring version higher than 3.1 and you have already defined your entities classes.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.demoJPA.model" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DemoJPAConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cimto");
        dataSource.setUser("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("cimtoPU");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaProperties());

        return em;
    }

    public Map<String, ?> getJpaProperties() {
    return new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    public JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        return vendorAdapter;
    }
}
```

Note: `com.demoJPA.model` package must contain your entities classes.

Comment: Additional note : there may be no compilation error, but make sure Spring support the matching hibernate version. E.g. Spring 4.2 is the first to support Hibernate 5.0, Spring 4.3 is the first to support Hibernate 5.2.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a `PersistenceProvider` implementation (e.g. Hibernate), you can use the [PersistenceProvider#createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html#createContainerEntityManagerFactory-javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo-java.util.Map-) method to bootstrap an `EntityManagerFactory` without needing a `persistence.xml`.

However, it's annoying that you have to implement the `PersistenceUnitInfo` interface, so you are better off using Spring or Hibernate which both support bootstrapping JPA without a `persistence.xml` file:

```
this.nativeEntityManagerFactory = provider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(
    this.persistenceUnitInfo, 
    getJpaPropertyMap()
);
```

Where the [`PersistenceUnitInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html) is implemented by the Spring-specific [`MutablePersistenceUnitInfo`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/MutablePersistenceUnitInfo.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve and in what context (ApplicationServer vs CLI, [CMT transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) vs [EntityTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html)s), it may be possible to use JPA without a `persistence.xml`. I did this in a CLI Java application, where I had different databases with the same structure. For that I constructed the `EntityManagerFactory` manually.

PS: The config file is there to make your life easier, so if you can, just use it.