# Swing project JPA without persistence.xml?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm creating a project with swing and JPA, it works fine, but now I want to change this project to work with JPA without persistence.xml file. I'm looking for some example but still haven't found any solution. I know that with Spring has way but with swing I don't know.

There's some way to do this, how to do ?

Comment: How do you expect to configure your persistence units then?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I think the way is to create a Class to configure like in Spring, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905908/jpa-without-persistence-xml

Comment: @BillyFrost I'm creating a `persistence.xml` and set the `persistence-unit`, after this I creating a Java Class to return EntityManager, it works fine, but I want to know if does any way to create this persistence.xml programatically ?

Comment: Nope. JPA does not include that as a valid use case, and this question is nothing to do with Swing ... Swing will use data retrieved by JPA but has nothing to do with JPA. Suggest you untag Swing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The JPA always need a `persistence.xml` but I can create a simple `persistence.xml` setting only one  `persistence-unit` and after I can create a class to define values of connection and others.

**here the persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="default">    
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>    
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**and here the class where I setting the values**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitTransactionType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;

/**
 *
 * @author fernando
 */
public class JPAUtils {  
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "default"; 
    private static final String DB_NAME = "iguanaauto_db";
    public static String IP_SERVER = "127.000.000.001";

    /** return an entitymanagerfactory */
    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){        
        if(emf == null){
            PersistenceProvider pp = new PersistenceProvider();
            Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();            
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.TRANSACTION_TYPE, PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL.name());                      
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_URL, "jdbc:mysql://" + IP_SERVER + ":3306/" + DB_NAME + "?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_USER, "root");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_PASSWORD, "");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_GENERATION, PersistenceUnitProperties.CREATE_OR_EXTEND);
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_GENERATION_MODE, PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_DATABASE_GENERATION);
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.LOGGING_LEVEL, "FINE");            
            emf = pp.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT, properties);
        }
        return emf;
    }

}
```