# How can I translate JPA xml configuration into a java class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to a configure JPA in a java class (not using the usual `persistence.xml` approach)

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    Configuration configuration=new Configuration();

    Properties settings= new Properties();

    settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "");
    settings.put(Environment.URL, "");
    settings.put(Environment.USER, "");
    settings.put(Environment.PASS, "");
    settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "");
    settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
    settings.put(Environment.DEFAULT_SCHEMA, "");
    configuration.setProperties(settings);
     configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Passenger.class);  
     ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
             .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
     sessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

}
```

Comment: Those are two different things. What have you tried?

Comment: i m try with java class

Comment: what properties is used in java class

Comment: You can follow https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-5-java-configuration-example this article.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA without persistence.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905908/jpa-without-persistence-xml)

Comment: To state the blindingly obvious, what you post IS NOT THE JPA API. Neither is the DZone article listed above. If you really mean HIBERNATE API then kindly state it and remove the JPA tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot (or don't want) use the standard XML configuration, you can bootstrap `JPA` via a custom implementation. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bootstrap-jpa) is an example. 
If you provide more info about your desired result (dialect, persistence unit name etc.) I can give you a more detailed example.